# Azure Storage Operational Backup Creating new version after Restore

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, blobstorage, azure-backup-vault

I have restored the azure storage entire containers using operation backup restore point. Now the restore is successful but I can see the Current version is also preserved in versions(Versioning is enabled). Is it possible that there will be no any version after restore.  e.g. If I made changes to Blob A then I have one version created. But If I restore then it again restore the base blob but modified blob again present in versions.

Comment: So is this expected behavior ? Can be avoided ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the retrieved documents, it is not possible to restore a blob without creating a new version.

The versioning feature in Azure Blob Storage is designed to preserve all versions of a blob, including the base blob and any modifications made to it. Therefore, after restoring a blob, the base blob will be restored, and the modified blob will still be present in the versions.

[image]

> Yes, this is the expected behaviour. When you restore a blob from a backup, the base blob is restored, and any modifications made to it are preserved in the versions. This is because the versioning feature in Azure Blob Storage is designed to preserve all versions of a blob, including the base blob and any modifications made to it.

The purpose of versioning in Azure Storage

- To provide data protection and the ability to recover previous versions of blobs. By preserving all versions, including the modified version after a restore, you can maintain a full version history of your data.

If you want to remove the modified version after a restore and keep only the restored version as the current version, then you need to manually delete the historical version.
This can be done using Azure Storage SDKs, [Azure Storage REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-blob?tabs=azure-ad), or Azure Storage Explorer by deleting the specific version of the blob.

For more information, refer this [Blob versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview) and [Enable and manage blob versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-enable?tabs=portal).

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh. And if we restore the container to primary region then after restore later it will automatically restore to secondary region as well ? If storage account is GRS.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).